# SVG graph and table is collapsing when not given a specific size

Tags: anychart

So I have a graph and table that show results according to the number of flights, but I want their size to be automatic, but right now if I don't give the div that is wrapping them together a specific size, they will end up collapsing. See the attachment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G85dG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The div container cannot be resized by charts. All charts as a default fir to the div container. It means that you should define the div size by CSS manually, for example, 100% of the parent's element or specific size in px.
Inside the div, you can adjust the table and chart manually.
In the comment below you can find the sample of a table and a column chart. Every one of them is 50% height of the div container. And the div container occupies 100% of the `body`.